# Filtered scanf causing infinite loop

Tags: c, scanf

I've got in one program filtered input via scanf.
I want read only numbers and big letters + spaces.

Recently I was trying to do something like that, and it stuck in an infinite loop, still printing only first input.
I know about `fgets()`, but I know this worked.
I can't find out where the problem is.
Here's simplified situation; what is happening to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[21];

  do
  {
    scanf("%20[0-9A-Z ]", str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
  } while(strcmp("END", str) != 0);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, input is valid, for input: "HELLO" program stuck...and `scanf` return 1 only for first input, for others returning 0.
And I also tried `fflush(stdin)`, after reading...

Comment: Its better you use `getc(stdin)` and check the character till it gets 20 valid characters.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - yep, i know about these functions, but i want to make it with scanf(), because, times ago, i made something with it..

Comment: Better first read the user input, then evaluate its contents via `sscanf()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scanf` accepts only digits, upper case letters (latin alphabet) and spaces,

```
scanf("%20[0-9A-Z ]", str);
```

so when you enter anything else, `scanf` fails to assign input to `str`, and the offending input remains in the input buffer. You need to check whether the scan succeeded and clear the input buffer on failure.

And since in particular newlines are not among the valid input tokens, you need to clear the input buffer until the next newline anyway if the input comes from e.g. the keyboard and not a newline-free input stream.

```
int c;
do
{
  scanf("%20[0-9A-Z ]", str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // clear input buffer
} while(c != EOF && strcmp("END", str) != 0);
```

Comment: How does the programme receive the input? Note that newlines will be invalid input too.

Comment: Okay, then it's the newline for sure.

Comment: Fischer - Yes, you're right...it was first think i thought it is bad, so i tried fflush(stdin) after readin...it didn't work, why? :)

Comment: @hradecek calling `fflush` on input streams is undefined behaviour per the standard, although some implementations say that it would discard any already-read-but-not-yet-consumed data from the buffer, it seems to be unreliable even there.

Comment: @igaar `str` is correct, the array name is converted to a pointer to its first element when passed as a function argument. In all sensible implementations `&str` would work too, since it points to the same address, but it's the wrong type, `char (*)[21]` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the input a bit - but you could check that scanf worked - it will return the number of matched expressions - so should be 1 in this case.
If its 0 - its not matching the input, so it may stick where it is.