# How to stop infinite loop when character is pressed in place of int?

Tags: c

Here, user is asked to press respective key to perform particular function, but suppose I pressed any character value such as "g", it goes into an infinite loop.

How to solve this issue?

```
int item,choice;
clrscr();
while(1)
{
printf("QUEUE SIMULAtOR");
printf("\n1:Insert");
printf("\n2:Delete");
printf("\n3:Display");
printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
scanf("%d",&choice);
switch(choice)
{
case 1:qinsert();
break;
case 2:item=qdelete();
if(item!=-1)
printf("Deleted item is %d",item);
break;
case 3:printf("\nElements in the queue are:");
qdisplay();
break;
case 4:exit(0);
default:printf("\nWrong choice try again:");
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtered scanf causing infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902189/filtered-scanf-causing-infinite-loop)

Comment: stop using `scanf()`. It's an inherently flawed function (there's no such thing as "formatted input"). Use `fgets()` to get an entire line, and dedicated parser and conversion functions to parse the line (e. g. `strtok_r()` and `strtol()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after the `scanf()`

```
char ch;

while( ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' && ch != EOF );
```

This should do the trick.

The problem was caused as `scanf()` does not store characters ( since you are using %d ) and thus they remain in the input buffer. The next `scanf()` tries to read this and again, instead of storing it, ignores it and it remains in the buffer. This process repeats, which causes the infinite loop.

The code I gave reads all the characters in the buffer, thus reomoving the infinite loop.

Cheers... Hope this helps you   :)

Comment: @SiddhantSingh , inside the while loop, there is a `getchar()` which reads a character from stdin ( the buffer ), and it continues to read all the characters until a `'\n'` is encountered. You must also see the semicolon `;` after the while loop, so that nothing beyond it is included in the loop. Read this [Use of getchar()](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/class/een218/getchar.html)

Comment: @SiddhantSingh , simply put, this code reads all the values in stdin until `'\n'` is encountered, thus in your case, it will remove the character you entered. There have been many questions related to such issues asked on Stack Overflow, so I believe you can search for it and it would help you way better than I can explain. Read this also [How to flush the console buffer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573457/how-to-flush-the-console-buffer)

Answer (score -1):

This is a really awesome question.You must try to use a break statement inside a `if()`.

Example:

```
void main()
{

int n;

 printf("Enter the number 5\n");
while(1)
{
      scanf("%d",n);
      if(n==5)
      { break;
                         }
      else
      {
            printf(" enter the correct num again \n");

           }
   }
   printf(" you've entered the right number\n");

   }
```

There you go this program will run until u enter the number 5

If you want any integer 
you could use `isdigit()` function which is under the header file `ctype`

Comment: First of all, its `scanf("%d",&n);`. Secondly, how is this answer trying to solve this question ? I don't see how this is useful.